# Python filter log file and sum up the filter

Tags: python

```
Jun 23 10:10:03 145.89.109.1 : %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP: list 120 denied icmp 145.89.182.65 -> 145.89.109.49 (0/0), 6 packets 
Jun 23 10:18:40 145.89.109.1 : %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP: list 120 denied icmp 95.9.149.232 -> 145.89.109.49 (0/0), 1 packet 
Jun 23 10:57:05 145.89.109.1 : %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP: list 120 denied icmp 169.244.237.130 -> 145.89.109.49 (0/0), 3 packets
```

this is a part of the log file. My question is, how can I filter the amount of packets and sum them up. So I need to sum 6, 1 and 3 up. How do I first filter the information of the amount of packets and than sum them up?

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
data = StringIO(
    """
Jun 23 10:10:03 145.89.109.1 : %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP: list 120 denied icmp 145.89.182.65 -> 145.89.109.49 (0/0), 6 packets 
Jun 23 10:18:40 145.89.109.1 : %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP: list 120 denied icmp 95.9.149.232 -> 145.89.109.49 (0/0), 1 packet 
Jun 23 10:57:05 145.89.109.1 : %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP: list 120 denied icmp 169.244.237.130 -> 145.89.109.49 (0/0), 3 packets
""")
```

UPDATE without regex:
Since you don't know regex, here is a solution without it. Notice, that this relys on the fact, that everytime `"%SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP"` is found in a line, at the end has to be some kind of number with packets.

```py
with open('router1.log', 'r') as data:
    out = []
    for line in data:
        if "%SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP" in line:
            # split the line and the last chunk after a "," will assigned to the variable "pack"
            *_, pack = line.split(",") 
           
            # split the number from the word packet
            num, word = pack.strip().split(" ")
    
            out.append(int(num))

result = sum(out)
print(result)
# [6, 1, 3]
```

old answer:
You could do it with a regex search and extract the number before packet.
(**update** converted code into function as in the comments asked)

```
import re

def icmp_packets(filename):
    pattern = r"(\d+)\s?packets?"
    with open(filename, 'r') as data:
        total_sum = 0
        for line in data:
            if "%SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP" in line:
                res = re.search(pattern, line)
                if res:
                    total_sum += int(res.group(1))
    return total_sum

result = icmp_packets('router1.log')
print(result)
# 10
```

You could also do a list, append each match to it and build the sum of that list at the end if you want to keep track of the seperate packets.

```
pattern = r"(\d+)\s?packets?"
out = []
with open('router1.log', 'r') as data:
    for line in data: # search line by line for the pattern
        m = re.search(pattern, line)
        if m: # if there is a match in a line
            out.append(int(m.group(1))) # convert the match to an int and add it

result = sum(out) # [6, 1, 3]
print(result)
# 10
```

check out that regex pattern at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wMwHXO/1)

Comment: What does the pattern variable? And do you know how i can filter it first if %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGDP is in the line, so it first checks if %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGD is in the line, if thats the case it filters out the amount of packets

Comment: regex = regular expression. It is a way to match strings of text such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters, here for example, the pattern searches for 1, or more number of digits followed by the word packet. If you google regex python, there are tons of stuff on it. I will update my code with your extra condition

Comment: Thnaks mate, last question haha, i have a file where i need those lines, how can i make the code read the file instead of only the 3 lines i have provide? filename is router1.log

Comment: go for regular expression. Its much more easier approach than anything else.

Comment: I'd also recommend regex, but I thought, if he never heard of it before, he wants a different approach. I updated my post. import your data with a context manager (I called it data aswell, so you just can copy paste my code)

Comment: okay last last question can you make a definition of it?

Comment: lots of question :D. what do you mean by definition? for what?

Comment: like def packets():

Comment: ah you mean a function. come on, don't you think you can do that? ;) simple function, with the filename as one input argument, and at the end you return the result of your sum. if you don't get it done, write me again here, but I'd say you should try it first on your own.

Comment: well i tried it, probably doing something wrong. I did def icmp_packets(data):
(code)
return result

Comment: I updated my answer in the code with the regex pattern. You'll see. I'd really appreciate if you accept this as an answer if you are happy with the code :)

Comment: you're welcome. please vote and accept my answer as official answer. i put a lot of time in it now :D this is my reward.